# How to prove a function from R to R^2 is a manifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, parametrization, implicit-function-theorem

Consider the function $\gamma : \mathbb R → \mathbb R^2 $ defined by $\begin{pmatrix}
\sin(t)\\
\sin(2t)
\end{pmatrix} $
$M$ = {$z= \gamma (t)$for some $t $ $\epsilon$ $ (0,1)$} 
How do I show that this is a manifold without using the parameterization method.

I understand how to prove it is a manifold using the parameterization but how would I go backwards to use the implicit function theorem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The implicit function theorem applies to maps with surjective differential, which $\gamma$ does not have.

Comment: exactly where my confusion is! I have to solve the problem in 2 different ways, so I solved it using the parameterization. What other method should I use and how?

Answer (score 1):

You may apply the preimage theorem. Since $\sin(2t)=2\sin t \cos t$ and $\cos t>0$ when $t\in (0,1)$, we have $\sin(2t)=2\sin t \sqrt{1-\sin^2 t}$. Plug in $x=\sin t, y=\sin (2t)$, we see that the manifold is determined by equation $2x\sqrt{1-x^2}-y=0$.

Consider map $f=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}-y:(0, \sin 1)\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Since 
$\partial f/\partial y=-1$, $0$ is a regular value of $f$ and hence $f^{-1}0=M$ is a 
manifold.